# Devise redirect after restoring password fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

How can i redirect to some custom page if a user hits the restore password button with the email input field empty? Now i'm redirected to `users/password` page. Devise doesn't provide any method to do it. Another point is that explanation message should be available(ex. "`Email should not be blank.`") on the page i'm redirected to.

Answer (score 2):

You need to sub-class Devise's `passwords_controller.rb` and override the `create` method to do so.

In `app/controllers/my_passwords_controller.rb`:

```
class MyPasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  # POST /resource/password
  def create
    self.resource = resource_class.send_reset_password_instructions(params[resource_name])

    if resource.errors.empty?
      set_flash_message(:notice, :send_instructions) if is_navigational_format?
      respond_with resource, :location => new_session_path(resource_name)
    else

      # Redirect to custom page instead of displaying errors
      redirect_to my_custom_page_path

      # respond_with_navigational(resource){ render_with_scope :new }

    end
  end
end
```

Then change your `routes.rb` to tell devise to use this controller :

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :passwords => :my_passwords }
```

Comment: And how can I customize error messages in this method? `resource.errors` is available in this method but it contains default messages such as `Email not found` and `Email can't be blank`. i need to customize this messages. I've tried to remove :validatable from my user model and add custom validators but this works only for my custom registrations controller derived from  `Devise::RegistrationsController` and not for custom passwords controller.

Comment: The simplest might be to create a custom page somewhere and redirect there if the email was not found (or any error on the Devise::Password for that matter). I've updated the code in my example to reflect that.